# Numpy 3D array arranging and reshaping

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array that I need to reshape and arrange. For example, I have `x=np.array([np.array([np.array([1,0,1]),np.array([1,1,1]),np.array([0,1,0]),np.array([1,1,0])]),np.array([np.array([0,0,1]),np.array([0,0,0]),np.array([0,1,1]),np.array([1,0,0])]),np.array([np.array([1,0,0]),np.array([1,0,1]),np.array([1,1,1]),np.array([0,0,0])])])`

Which is a shape of (3,4,3), when printing it I get:

```
array([[[1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

Now I need to reshape this array to a `(4,3,3)` by selecting the same index in each subarray and putting them together to end up with something like this:

```
array([[[1,0,1],[0,0,1],[1,0,0]],
[[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[1,0,1]],
[[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]],
[[1,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,0]]]
```

I tried `reshape`, all kinds of stacking and nothing worked (arranged the array like I need). I know I can do it manually but for large arrays manually isn't a choice.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You can simplify the array creation to: `x= np.array([[[1,0,1], [1,1,1],...,1,1], [0,0,0]]])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`swapaxes`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) will do what you want.  That is, if your input array is `x` and your desired output is `y`, then

```
np.all(y==np.swapaxes(x, 1, 0))
```

should give `True`.

Comment: Also, possibly `rollaxis`. In this case the two will probably be equivalent, but for higher-dimensioned arrays, `rollaxis` is often the one you want since it preserves the order of the other axes better.

Comment: Not sure why this isn't included under "See also" in the [numpy documentation for reshape()](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

Answer (score 1):

For higher dimensional arrays, transpose will accept a tuple of axis numbers to permute the axes:

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]], [[9, 10], [11, 12]]])
foo.transpose(1, 0, 2)
```

result:

```
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 5,  6],
        [ 9, 10]],

       [[ 3,  4],
        [ 7,  8],
        [11, 12]]])
```

Comment: Sometimes a 5 year old answer with no upvotes can save you tons of time. I'm happy I found this, thank you!